# Asynchronus insert in Azure cloud table

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

I am trying to insert a record in azure table on some specific condition. What I found that the records are not getting saved all the time. Few times it works and few times its not. Here is the code which I have written to execute the insert. In addition to that, the code is written to insert a single record for each call and its never going to save multiple records at a time. Also I don't want to wait for the insert operation nor I want to do it synchronously. I want to do it asynchronously and that is without wait.

why the code sometimes fails to insert the records?

Here is my code snippet

```
try
{
    AuditUtils utils = new AuditUtils((int)this.User.Id);
    String tableName = "ServiceHeaderInfo", partitionKey = this.Header.PrimaryAccount;
    TableAuditEntity tableAuditEntity = utils.GetAuditEntity(tableName, partitionKey, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), TableAuditTypes.Insert, refId, refType);
    tableAuditEntity["DeviceIdentifier"] = this.Header.DeviceId;
    tableAuditEntity["DeviceModel"] = this.Header.DeviceModel;
    tableAuditEntity["OSVersion"] = this.Header.OSVersion;
    

    utils.AddAsync(tableAuditEntity).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        var ex = t.Exception?.GetBaseException();
        if (ex != null)
        {
            this.HandleError(ex);
        }
    }, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    this.HandleError(ex);
}

public async Task<TableResult> AddAsync(string tableName, SampleTableEntity entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var table = await GetTableAsync(tableName);
        return await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity), cancellationToken);
    }
```

Comment: I want it in a way to perform the operation asynchronously but shouldn't wait. therefore the return task is not being used. Also the reason behind continue with is for error handing. It will not blocking a thread and when the operation done, again other thread will be in place to handle it. Please suggest, why it will not insert the record all the time.

Answer (score 0):

​It is not possible `Async` without `Wait`.

You need to use

```
ExecuteAsync(TableOperation)`
```

or

```
ExecuteAsync(TableOperation, TableRequestOptions, OperationContext) methods is used to achieve the requirement.
```

Instead of **above methods** you have

```
 ExecuteAsync(TableOperation, CancellationToken)
```

&

```
ExecuteAsync(TableOperation, TableRequestOptions, OperationContext, CancellationToken)
```

When you use  **CancellationToken**  it must have a  **TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll** method.

In a cancellation of the operation, it instantiates a *CancellationTokenSource* object that generates a cancellation token that's passed to a *TaskFactory* object.

In turn, the *TaskFactory* object passes the cancellation token to each of the tasks responsible for collecting readings for a particular instrument.

The `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll<TAntecedentResult, TResult>(Task<TAntecedentResult>[], Func<Task<TAntecedentResult>[],TResult>, CancellationToken)` method is called to ensure that  **computed**  only after all **readings have been gathered successfully**.

If a task has  **not completed**  because it was  **cancelled**, the *TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll* method  **throws an exception.**

Please refer: [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtable.executeasync?view=azure-dotnet)